# Left-align two text boxes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I'm a beginner of AI. I very often need to left-align two text boxes. Sometimes, I can just move one around the other, and a "glyphbound" can appear. But the "glyphbound" does not always appear.

I understand that there are point type and area type, but it does not seem that they are related to this alignment.

Are there other ways to left-align two text boxes? For instance, select the two boxes, and click on something?

Comment: The align tools should work as stated by Scott in his answer, however you can also [do this with Smart Guides](https://imgur.com/wWRk6XL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **align buttons** across the top of the screen in the **Control Bar**.

Or.. choose `Window > Align` to open the **Align Panel**.

[image]

Select more than one object and tap the button for the align option you want...

These also work to align anchor points, **if** you select *more than one* anchor point, but *not all* anchor points for an object.